# Resampling an array by duplicating or skipping items (translate numpy to js)

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, numpy, math

I am trying to translate this python/numpy code I have into javascript. This method takes an array and a target size and resizes the array by duplicating or skipping every N items.

Here is an example:

```js
let original_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
upsample(original_array, 12);
// returns [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is my working python/numpy code:

```py
import numpy as np

upsample(arr, target_size):
    original_array = np.array(arr)
    x = np.linspace(0, original_array.size, num=target_size, endpoint=False)
    x = original_array[x.astype(int)]
    return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using this node module that copies matlab's linspace behaviour: https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-linspace

Here is the code:

```js
const linspace = require('linspace');

function upsample(arr, targetSize) {
  let newArr = new Array(targetSize);
  let lin = linspace(0, arr.length, targetSize);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      lin[i] = parseInt(lin[i]);
  for (let j = 0; j < newArr.length-1; j++)
      newArr[j] = arr[lin[j]];
  return newArr;
}
```